# WEKA PartitionMembership filter

Tags: filter, weka

I have a question regarding the supervised PartitionMembership filter in WEKA.
When applying this filter using J48 as partition generator, I am able to achieve a much higher accuracy in combination with the KStar classifier.

What does this filter exactly do, because the documentation provided by WEKA is quite limited? And is it valid to use this filter to get an increased accuracy?

When applying this filter on my trainings set, it generates a number of classes. When I try to reapply the model on my test set, the filter generates a different number of classes. Hence, I am not able to use this trained supervised PartitionMembership filter for my test set. How can I use the PartitionMembership filter that was trained on the training set also for the test set?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two or three questions here. Regarding the first two: What does the PartitionMembership filter do, and how do I use it? - That I don't know to answer properly. Ultimately you can read the [source code](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/PartitionMembership.java) to check it out.

For the latter question, (~ how do I get it to evaluate my test set), Please use the FilteredClassifier, and there choose your filter and your classification in the dialog box of that classifier.

> NAME weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier
>
> SYNOPSIS Class for running an arbitrary classifier on data that has
>   been passed through an arbitrary filter. Like the classifier, the
>   structure of the filter is based exclusively on the training data and
>   test instances will be processed by the filter without changing their
>   structure.